# R Shiny App: Export the dataframe from plotly to Excel

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, plotly

I create a graphic from a dataframe with renderPloly. I now want to write the data (dataframe) of the plot into an Excel file. Here is my code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    
    Daten_gefiltert<-filter(RRK_A, RRK_A$Datum >= input$Datumsbereich_A[1] & RRK_A$Datum <= input$Datumsbereich_A[2])
    

    
    
    if(nrow(Daten_gefiltert)>0){
      
    Daten_gefiltert<-arrange(Daten_gefiltert,Datum,Meßzeitpunkt)
    #Window_A_N<-299
    Daten_gefiltert <- Daten_gefiltert %>%
      mutate(CRR_A_filter=roll_sum(Daten_gefiltert$CRR_A_Flag, Window_A_N, align = "right", fill = NA))
    
    Daten_gefiltert$CRR_A_filter<-Daten_gefiltert$CRR_A_filter/Window_A_N*100
    
    
    Daten_gefiltert_A<-Daten_gefiltert
    
    Text_Subtitle<-paste(subtitle = Text_Subtitle," \n Anzahl Datenpunkte:",as.character(nrow(Daten_gefiltert)),sep=" ")
    
    Sub_title<-paste("Gebäude:",paste(input$`Gebäude_ZDIM_A`,collapse = ","),
                     "; Raum:",input$`Räume_ZDIM_A`,
                     "; Methode:",input$Methode_A,
                     "; Linie:",input$Linie_A,
                     "; Raumgruppe:",input$Raumgruppe_A,
                     "; Verarbeitungsbelege:",input$Verarbeitungsstatus_A)
    
    Title_text<-paste(  '<b>CRR RRK A</b>',
                        '<br><sup>',
                        Sub_title,
                        '</sup>'
    )
    
    
    
    y_label <-paste("CRR [%> 0 KBE]")                 
    
    p22<-plot_ly(data=Daten_gefiltert, x=~ Datum, y=~ CRR_A_filter, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines' )
    
    p22<-p22%>%layout(title = Title_text,yaxis = list(title = list(text =y_label)),
                      shapes=list(type = "line", 
                                  x0 = 0, 
                                  x1 = 1, 
                                  xref = "paper",
                                  y0 = 1, 
                                  y1 = 1, 
                                  line = list(color = "red" )))
    
    p22<-p22%>%add_annotations(xref="paper",yref="paper",x=0, y=-0.15,  text=Text_Subtitle,showarrow= F, font=list(size = 10))
    
    }else{
      p2<-ggplot() +                      # Draw ggplot2 plot with text only
        annotate("text",
                 x = 1,
                 y = 0,
                 size = 10, 
                 label = "Keine Daten vorhanden") + theme_void()
    }
    
    
    
  })
 output$download_excel <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("RRK_A_", Sys.Date(), ".xlsx")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write_xlsx(Daten_gefiltert_A, file)
                
    }
  )
```

I get the following error message:

**Warning: Error in write_xlsx: object 'Daten_gefiltert_A' not found**

How can I transfer the dataframe 'Daten_gefiltert_A' to the downloadHandler ?

Thanks for any hints

Comment: Daten_getiltert_A is only defined inside the “server” function.  Either save the variable to the global environment with <<- or save it within the server function.

Comment: Dave2e; thanks a loot,it works!